# The differences between BEM and SUIT CSS naming conventions

Tags: css, naming-conventions, bem, suit-css

What are the differences between [BEM](http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/) and [SUIT CSS](https://github.com/suitcss/suit/blob/master/doc/naming-conventions.md) naming conventions?

Comment: @Paulie_D Well I'm specifically asking for examples outside of opinions. I have zero interest in hearing someone's opinion on why they prefer one over the other!

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the difference between BEM and SUIT CSS naming conventions. That is something with a definitive answer and related to programming, therefore it is very much on-topic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to bem.info ([source](https://en.bem.info/method/definitions/)):

> We use hyphen to separate words in long names […] and two underscores to separate the name of the block form the name of the element […]
>
> But you can use any other separators for it.

So, it's possible to use BEM with another syntax. The syntax of *SUIT CSS* is a valid alternative syntax for BEM.

Additionally, Nicolas Gallagher renamed *blocks* (BEM) to *components* (SUIT), and *elements* (BEM) to  *descendants* (SUIT).

> Is one better suited for certain types of projects the other?

If you plan to use the full BEM methodology (see [this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/07/17/bem-methodology-for-small-projects/) for an example), including the tools from Yandex, then keep the original BEM conventions.

Otherwise, it's up to your preference.